# XSLT find whether sibling exist or not

Tags: xslt, xpath

Sample XML is given below.

```
<mapNode>
      <mapNode>...</mapNode>
      <mapNode>...</mapNode>-----I am here at 2
      <mapNode>...</mapNode>
      <mapNode>...</mapNode>
</mapNode>
<mapNode>
      <mapNode>...</mapNode>
      <mapNode>...</mapNode>
</mapNode>
```

I want to know whether position 3 exist or not.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to test if an element has a sibling following it, you can use the sensibly named "following-sibling" xpath expression:

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::*" />
```

Note that this will test if there is any following-sibling. If you only wanted to test for **mapNode** elements, you could do this

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::mapNode" />
```

However, this would also be true also in the following case, because following-sibling will look at all following siblings:

```
<mapNode> 
   <mapNode>...</mapNode> 
   <mapNode>...</mapNode>-----I am here at 2 
   <differentNode>...</differentNode> 
   <mapNode>...</mapNode> 
</mapNode>
```

If you therefore want to check the most immediately following sibling was a **mapNode** element, you would do this:

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::mapNode]" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @rene's answer you could also use the `following-sibling` axis from within any `mapNode`:

```
<xsl:template match="mapNode">
    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::mapNode)>0">
    <!-- has a successor -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what you already have but assuming you have a template to select a toplevel mapNode you can use [count](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2018.html) to findout how many mapNodes there are under thecurrent node:

```
   <xsl:template match="/root/mapNode">
      <xsl:if test="count(mapNode)>2">
        more than two mapNodes
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```